# robotframework dictionary variables click through

Tags: robotframework

could someone help me with this please.
find attached [dictionary.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7pSG.png)

Questions:

1. Why Intellij says that `No Usage found in Project Files` for
   dictionaries? when I try to click through. does anyone know?
2. Its
   clearly in the robot test file under `variables` section

The reason why I'm trying to tackle is:
- All these dictionaries I've crated for other tests are moved to separate files in `data` directory.
- Therefore click through is quite important to see the value of the dictionary keys.

```
Versions:
- Python - 2.7.12
- IntelliBot - 0.10.143.381
- Robot framework plugin - 0.16.3


- Pip list
apipkg (1.4)
Appium-Python-Client (0.24)
certifi (2017.7.27.1)
chardet (3.0.4)
colorama (0.3.9)
coverage (4.4.1)
decorator (4.1.2)
docutils (0.13.1)
execnet (1.4.1)
idna (2.5)
mock (1.0.1)
oauthlib (2.0.4)
pip (9.0.1)
py (1.4.34)
pytest (3.1.3)
pytest-cov (2.5.1)
pytest-pythonpath (0.7.1)
pytest-xdist (1.18.2)
requests (2.18.2)
requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
robotframework (3.0.2)
robotframework-appiumlibrary (1.4.4)
robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary (0.5.5)
robotframework-pageobjectlibrary (0.1.7)
robotframework-requests (0.4.7)
robotframework-selenium2library (1.8.0)
sauceclient (1.0.0)
selenium (3.5.0)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
urllib3 (1.22)
```

Plz help and let me know if you need further info

thanks

Comment: This just looks like a bug in IntelliBot. Have you contacted the person who wrote that plugin?

Comment: Hey Bryan,
thanks for the response & suggestion, I wasn't sure where the bug is, I'll contact the IntelliBot dev's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IntelliJ IDE, the `Find Usage` feature is not reliable. It's a known bug, but according to [the responses to this post on the JetBrains community site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207058515-Find-usages-not-working-reliably-) the fix is to get the latest version of IntelliJ. If you have the latest version of IntelliJ and you're still getting this bug, ignore it. It shouldn't affect your code execution. It's a bug in a supposed-to-be helpful tool, not the end-all be-all information readout.

Comment: Hey Brandon, thanks for the swift response.
BTW im on the latest intellij


**IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 Build #IC-172.4343.14, built on September 26,** **2017**
**JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 amd64**
**JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o**
**Windows 7 6.1**


looks like a bug in Intellij or intelliBot as mentioned by Bryan.Oakley